# ContentResolver not returning fresh data for Calendar events

Tags: android, calendar

How do I get fresh list of events from Calendar using ContentResolver?

I have used following line of code for the same

```
ContentResolver cr = AppController.getInstance().getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,new String[]{"calendar_id", "title", "description","dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation", "_id"}, null,null, null);
```

This returns me list of calendar events, but the problem is, if I manually remove an event from Calendar app and then resume my app, still ContentResolver returns with the same deleted event.
But if I force restart my app, then it returns proper data.

Please suggest for any solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `android.app.LoaderManager` for that

Comment: @pskink, thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion, but it still results with the deleted calendar event.
I have tried initializing loader manager from onResume and onCreate, so that it can fetch fresh calendar events, but still the same issue :(

Comment: i just used [this](http://pastebin.com/G5E5gbDi) in `onCreate` and it reloads every time you add / modify / delete events from `Calendar` app, post your code what you did

Comment: @pskink, I went up using your suggestion, but still getting the same issue.
Please review the code [here](http://pastebin.com/gmWebaRp)

Comment: did you try my exact code? without any modifications?

Comment: @pskink, yes I did use it

Comment: and? when is `"onLoadFinished =================================="` shown on the logcat?

Comment: It takes almost takes a second..to show up in the logcat

Comment: what takes a second?

Comment: it takes almost 1 second to come into onLoadFinished in our app, once we delete any event from the calendar.

Comment: so are you getting up-to-date data or not?

Comment: yes I am getting data correctly but after some delay. I am trying to engage user till I get back into onLoadFinished after deleting event from Calendar app

Comment: i dont see any delay in the code i run

Comment: @pskink Facing similar issue. Could you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012807/android-calendar-provider-does-not-return-latest-data